# How to add array values using NSMutableArray in iPHone?

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, addition

I have the data into the mutable array and the value of array is,

```
     { "20", "40", "50","60", "70"}.
```

I have stored the string values into the array.

Now i want to total value of the array. Result is : 240

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSInteger value = 0;
for (String *digit in myArray) {
    value += [digit intValue];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int total=0;
for(NSString *currentString in myArray){
     total +=[currentString intValue]; 
}
NSLog(@"Sum:%d",total);
```

Answer (score 0):

This adds all values:

```
__block NSInteger sum = 0;
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    sum += [obj intValue];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
int totalSum = 0;
NSmutableArray *arrayData = [[NSmutableArray alloc] init];
[arrayData addObject:@"20"];
[arrayData addObject:@"40"];
[arrayData addObject:@"50"];
[arrayData addObject:@"60"];
[arrayData addObject:@"70"];

for(int i=0; i<[arrayData count];i++)
{
     totalSum = totalSum + [[arrayData objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
}

NSLog(@"Total:%d",totalSum);
```

Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: You forget `alloc` and `init` `arrayData`.

Comment: Now I changed my answer and also allocated the arrayData.

Answer (score 0):

How about the most elegant solution using key-value Collection aggregators:

```
NSNumber *sum = [myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];
```